# How to increment integer column1 value by 1 after sorting by column2 in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to create a SQL query that update values in the column "position" by incrementing an integer value by 1, after grouping by column "fruit" and sorting by (ASC) the column "weight".

Example:

Starting from this table:

```
id  | fruit | weight     | position  
1   | Apple | 200        |   0  
2   | Pear  | 180        |   0  
3   | Apple | 230        |   0  
4   | Grape | 100        |   0  
5   | Apple | 180        |   0  
6   | Grape | 120        |   0  
7   | Pear  | 150        |   0  
8   | Apple | 210        |   0  
9   | Apple | 240        |   0  
10  |Grape  |90          |   0  
11  |Pear   |130         |   0
```

I want to UPDATE the column "position" and get the following:

```
id  | fruit | weight     | position  
5   | Apple | 180        |   1  
1   | Apple | 200        |   2  
8   | Apple | 210        |   3  
3   | Apple | 230        |   4  
9   | Apple | 240        |   5  
10  | Grape | 90         |   1  
4   | Grape | 100        |   2  
6   | Grape | 120        |   3  
11  | Pear  | 130        |   1  
7   | Pear  | 150        |   2  
2   | Pear  | 180        |   3
```

where the column "position" increment the integer value (starting from 1) depending on the column "weight" and grouping by "fruit"

Comment: What dbms are you using? Mssql server, mysql, Oracle, postgresql, etc?

Comment: Better yet, drop the position column and select what you need when you need it, based on the requirements of that query.

Comment: Are the `(fruit, weight)` values unique or can there be duplicates?

Comment: I wouldn't store it but calculate it using row_number if your database supports it.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

This might be silly, but you can do the following:

```
update teh_table t1
set position = 1 + (select count(*)
                    from teh_table t2
                    where t2.fruit = t1.fruit
                      and t2.weight < t1.weight);
```

I.e. for each row, count the number of rows that have the same fruit but a lower weight, then add 1.